# Ajax call to Python

Tags: javascript, python, ajax

If I have the following code:

```
$('#do-updates').click(function() {
    $.post('/do_updates/', 
       function(response){
          location.reload();
    });
});
```

And the python function it calls is:

```
def do_update():
    for item in items:
        do something
```

The python function I call takes about 2m to finish.

If a user does the following:

```
1 - Click on the #do-updates button
2 - Navigate away from the page after 10s
```

What will happen? Will the entire `do_updates()` function run, because it is called asynchronously? Or will that function time out? If it does timeout, what's a better way to do the `do_updates()` function in the background so it will finish?

Comment: Which web framework on server side are you using?

Comment: You should implement this with some sort of push technology like Websockets and poll your server for progress information instead of waiting for a request to complete.

Comment: The ajax request will hang while the Python function runs. You better use a queue in the server. Celery is a popular choice for f

Comment: @PauloScardine -- right, let's say someone cancels out of the page. Excluding the ajax function, will the python function run to completion?

Comment: @user1383058: most likely it will run to completion even if the user leaves the page.

Answer (score 2):

If you dont need result of do_something on frontend you can use some of asynchronus task solution. [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org/) is probably most popular and simple to use with django.
It delegates work to dedicated worker which is running as different process through messaging queue(rabbitmq, redis, ..).